# How to find the sequence consists of prime numbers or odd numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

[image]

I tried to solve this question by finding any pattern. Also tried complex numbers but couldnot reach to a solution.
Please help me to understand this

Comment: I think the answer should be (b) as $a_n(a_n-1)$ is always even, so $a_{n+1}$ is always odd.

Comment: It may be a multiple option correct question @Cherryblossoms

Comment: Hint for $c$;  suppose you had a prime $p$ such that $p\,|\,a_i$ for some $i$.  Show that $p\,\nmid a_j$ for all $j>i$.

Comment: Note:  I can't sort out what $d$ is asking.

Comment: please also check <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is incorrect. $a_5=1807=13\times139$.

Now we will prove c). WLOG $i<j$. We will first prove that $a_j\equiv1\pmod{a_i}$ for $i<j$ using induction. First, we note $a_{i+1}=a^2_i-a_i+1\equiv1\pmod{a_i}$. Then suppose for $i<n<j$, $a_n\equiv1\pmod{a_i}$. Then, $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n^2-a_n+1\equiv1^2-1+1\equiv1\pmod{a_i}$. Thus $a_j\equiv1\pmod{a_i}$. $a_j$ is of the form $ma_i+1$ for some integer $m$, and $\gcd(a_i,a_j)=\gcd(a_i,ma_i+1)=\gcd(a_i,1)=1\forall j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

To prove b) we apply the fact that $\gcd(2,a_j)=1\forall j\geq2\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, i.e. $a_j$ is not even. But if $a_j$ is not even it must be odd.

Not sure what d) means.